# mysql - avoid escaping double quotes in json functions

Tags: mysql, json

When I issue...

```
select JSON_REPLACE('{"tbl" : "cnf"}', '$', '{"tbl":"cnf4"}');
```

I get the following :

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_REPLACE('{"tbl" : "cnf"}', '$', '{"tbl":"cnf4"}') |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| "{\"tbl\":\"cnf4\"}"                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

And it gets stored in my database the same say, with backslashes. I want to have no backslashes in my database. How can I achieve that?

I expect a reponse like: 
{"tbl":"cnf4"}

Comment: So do you want to fix the insert or need to take care of backslashed data on select? Or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap in JSON_UNQUOTE

```
select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_REPLACE('{"tbl" : "cnf"}', '$', '{"tbl":"cnf4"}'));
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_REPLACE('{"tbl" : "cnf"}', '$', '{"tbl":"cnf4"}')) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {"tbl":"cnf4"}                                                       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.0005 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What about this case, why is does not on unquote the value of the new replacement json object? `select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_REPLACE('{"tbl" : "shouldBeReplaced"}', '$.tbl', '{"newKey":"newValue"}')); `

Comment: results in `{"tbl": "{\"newKey\":\"newValue\"}"}`

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to unescape when I pushed new object to an existing array

```
json_array_append(data, '$', cast(? as json))
```